# jQuery Alpabetical Filter by name within a table, A,B,C etc list

Tags: jquery, html, css, filter

I have a working demo but only for a listview, I need to be able to click on the A,B,C etc list at the top then filter by the contact name within the table.

So as soon as you click on A, it will display all the names within the table that start with 'A'.

As i mentioned it works for a list view, but not sure how to get it working for within a table?

http://jsfiddle.net/37UxT/1/

Hope someone can help. Its based on a plugin from http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx Not sure where or how to do this manually as fairly new to jQuery.

```
$('ul.list-nav').listnav({         
    includeAll: false,                 
    noMatchText: 'Sorry, nothing matched this filter, please try another letter.', 
        includeAll: true, 
    initLetter: 'n', 
    showCounts: false                
});
```

Thanks

Comment: this is what I've found http://jsfiddle.net/hDxzP/76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are numerous "table sorter" plugins out there but this short and simple code could achieve what you're looking for

**Script**

```
     var alphas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var tmp = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < 26; x++) tmp += '<a href="#">' + alphas[x].toUpperCase() + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $('#table_filter').append(tmp);

        $('#table_filter a').click(function () {

           if ($(this).attr('id') == 'show_all') {
              $('#searchNames tbody tr').css('display', 'table-row');
              $('#message').html('displaying all rows');
              return false;
           }

           var alpha = $(this).html();
           $('#searchNames tbody tr').hide().filter(function () {
              var td = $('td:first', $(this));
              return td.length && td.html() && new RegExp('^' + alpha + '.*$', 'i').test(td.html().toLowerCase());
           }).css('display', 'table-row');
           $('#message').html('displaying rows with "' + alpha + '"');
           return false;
        })
     });
```

**AND The Markup**

```
  <div id="table_filter">
     <a id="show_all" href="#">Show All</a>
  </div>
  <p id="message"></p>
  <table class="table1" id="searchNames" style="width:500px;">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>CONTACT NAME</th>
           <th>col 2</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>ssfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>asdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>apodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>opkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>lkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>nlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>essfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>easdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qapodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>oopkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>dlkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>snlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>vqwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>ssfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>asdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>apodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>opkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>lkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>nlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>essfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>easdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qapodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>oopkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>dlkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>snlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>vqwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>ssfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>asdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>apodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>opkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>lkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>nlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>essfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>easdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qapodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>oopkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>dlkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>snlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>vqwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>ssfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>asdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>apodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>opkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>lkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>nlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>essfjkn jkdsnf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>easdl kln</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>qapodf</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>oopkpokj</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>dlkohasd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>snlkcn</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>vqwdsdfsd</td>
           <td>Col2</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

**And the jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Khq9k/2/

**UPDATE**

to make it filter based on 4th `<td>`, replace

```
var td = $('td:first', $(this));
```

with

```
var td = $('td:nth-child(4)', $(this));
```

Comment: Brilliant - how would you specify it to look for the contact name the 4th TD along??

Comment: Thank you again! Works a treat! :-) Dont suppose you know if highlighting td column is possible to give user indication of what column is found?

Comment: you mean always highlight column # 4 after filtering occurs?

Comment: Is it also possible to add a background colour on all items on the ABC list which have results in?

Comment: you mean always highlight column # 4 after filtering occurs? Yes - then when you un-filter the highlight fades away?

Comment: cheers worked a treat, regarding highlighting the <td> that the contact name is in. Would you just add a class do this when item is found then remove it?

Comment: $("td:nth-child(4)").addClass("highlightField").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                      $("td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("highlightField").fadeOut("slow");
                  });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27634/discussion-between-ejay-and-john)

Answer (score 0):

Above post didn't work for me on dynamic values fetched from database. I Tried writing something little less complex and worked as well.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var alphas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var tmp = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < 26; x++) tmp += '<a href="#">' + alphas[x].toUpperCase() + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $('#table_filter').append(tmp);

        $('#table_filter a').click(function () {
           var alpha = $(this).html();
           if(alpha == 'Show All'){
                $('#searchNames tbody tr').css('display', 'table-row');
           }
           else {
                $('#searchNames tbody tr').each(function( index ) {
                    var cur = $(':nth-child(1)', this).text().trim();
                    if(cur.charAt(0) === alpha) {
                        $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });

           }
        });
    });
```